# are missing dependencies in useEffect *always* mean bad design?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have this piece of code in my react component:

```
  const [editOrderComponentKey, setEditOrderComponentKey] = useState(0)

  // clear/reload EditOrderPanel on a freshly loaded order
  useEffect(() => {
    setEditOrderComponentKey(editOrderComponentKey + 1)
    /* eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
  }, [singleOrder])
```

the purpose of the code above, is to change the `editOrderComponentKey` when `singleOrder` has changed. I cannot put the editOrderComponentKey in the dependencies list, as the linter asks, because it will cause an infinite rendering, easy to see why.
anyway, this effect comes handy because few lines below I have the following code:

```
<EditOrderPanel orderId={orderId} key={`editOrder${editOrderComponentKey}`}/>
```

I want to invalidate `EditOrderPanel` if and only if `singleOrder` changes, so that `EditOrderPanel` would be re-mounted, and `EditOrderPanel`'s local state would get its defaults anew (useState default).
is there a way to design the code such that no linter disablement would be required on that line, and still being able to use uncontrolled components?

Comment: Nope, there are situations (like yours) when it is not possible to add all dependencies

Comment: Yes, missing dependencies are always bad, there is always a better way to implement your use case without missing dependencies (in my experience at least).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can use the callback version to get the previous value.

```
const [editOrderComponentKey, setEditOrderComponentKey] = useState(0)

useEffect(() => {
    setEditOrderComponentKey(prev => prev + 1)
}, [singleOrder, setEditOrderComponentKey])
```

Comment: I liked it and will be using it, but I am still left with the question - are missing dependencies always bad design or not :)

Comment: it appears that incrementing a counter is a classic problem, it also appears in Dan Avramov's article (https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) and he gives this very solution. Since this is a common pattern and a repetitive solution, why not just recognize it in the linter level and suggest this replacement

Comment: IMO it's usually a sign of bad design. With that said, I have run into situations myself where it was still the best of all the bad options. Everything else would have been even worse. Trying to mix reacts update cycles with external libraries that directly manipulate the DOM can lead to some interesting headaches for example.